Constraining Part in assembly by reference point
For starters I now have access to Inventor Professional 2023 and I am no longer restricted to Inventor Lite.
I am playing with inventor assemblies to see what I can get it to do for modelling bridge components.  Yes I realize that Inventor is probably not the best software for what I am doing.  I started with a small basic concrete bridge just to get a feel of its capabilities and restrictions.
I started by modelling the pile cap as a part, then the pile as a part, and I start to model the abutment and wingwalls as a part.
The pile cap is a basic rectangle with two tabs.  The whole thing is extruded up 700 mm and down 300 mm from its sketch plane.  In the image below you can see the black sketch behind the H-pile.  The centerline running through the sketch is for the the placement of the piles.  A point for each pile location is located along the centerline in the sketch. That whole thing is the pile cap part:

For the pile part, I placed centerlines in the sketch as well as a point on their intersection.  After extruding the part for 1 m I added an axis through the point to represent the length direction of the pile as seen below:

Since Inventor professional allows for assemblies, I started to refresh my memory and started an assembly.  For bridge construction we tend to work a lot with Work Points (WP), road alignments, road vertical profiles, and center lines. I noticed this does not seem to be the way Inventor likes to work (after all it was not intended for this).
Steps:

Inserted Pile Cap
Inserted Abutment
Constrained top of pile cap flush to bottom of abutment.
Constrained front of pile cap to front of abutment with offset
Constrained side of pile cap to side of abutment with offset

I would have preferred to have constrained centerlines of the abutment and pile cap to the same plane instead of dealing with face offset references.  Also would have preferred to had simply dropped the abutment WP on top of the footing pile cap WP.  However I have not figured out how to do that.  I figured I could fake it with a small pin and hole to lock the position of the two but I was wondering if there was another way as my pile placement process has hit a road block.
Question
How do I constrain the position of the pile part so that the center point of the pile is on the point for the pile in the pile cap sketch?
I originally thought of doing the same thing that I did for the abutment in terms of offsetting faces.  This seemed to be an annoyance as none of the references are to faces, just centerlines.  Then I realize this probably won't work as the pile also needs to be raked (sloped) in the front back direction.  This means that 2 of the 3 potential surfaces to match with will not have corresponding parallel planes.

I figured out a way to do it.  Not sure if it is an efficient method but it happens to work in my case...so far.
What I did was add axis lines in the pile cap sketch.  I was then able to add constraints to the axis from the pile and the axis to the pile cap.  That got me the sloped pile.  To get the top of the pile at the right location on the sketch I was able to select the cross section centerline and constrain it to the pile cap center line.

